# Using JMeter to simulate enties in to Database

Tags: c#, sql-server, jmeter

I'm trying to use Jmeter to simulate adding values, into a database from an ASP.NET website.

I have used the guide found here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zYAiBwJK1v8
To setup the test, and to record the scenario. All of that seems to be working fine. The recorder, records the login to the site, and everything that comes after, including when I push the submit button to add the value to my database. When i afterwards run the recorded scenario it runs with no errors. But nothing is submittet to the database.

The scenario is this: I login to my site, (i'm using browser session id to differ between users)
Now I search for an item, the search text is parsed along with the url (this i can also confirm in the recording, in Jmeter)
Then i add this item to a tabel row in my databse using a submit button. (this also seems to be working in the recording details in Jmeter)

But nothing is added to the database when i use Jmeter to re-run the scenario. Can any one help me to find out, why or what I am missing?

I'm not sure what more information to give, but if you need more information let me know and thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I'd recommend checking that your Log In is successful using [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener. At top left corner of the listener there will be a drop-down which defaults to `Text`. Select `HTML (download resources)` to see full response from server and verify if you're really logged in.

If not, refer to [ASP.NET Login Testing with JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/aspnet-login-testing-jmeter) guide which highlights the peculiarities of simulating ASP.NET application log in including VIEWSTATE and EVENTVALIDATION dynamic form parameters extraction.

Comment: Actually after some more testing, i found out that the login in was not successfull, it redirected back to the login page (as it should, if the session id does not match the user id in the database) To test beyond the login, i simply hardcoded the session id in my code to a number accepted by the rules i have set, and then its working just fine. So now i need to address the problem of why the session id is not set correctly. Thank you for your responce, i will try to have a look at your link, and then i will get back to you.